# How do get auto-completion on a compiled typescript lib that I authored?

Tags: typescript, package

I've just written a JS library in TypeScript that I'm now trying to use after installing it from NPM.

The lib has several classes which I want to extend from. This appears to work, but WebStorm is not giving me autocomplete, which I assume is because I've not configured something (either in the package or in the app) correctly.

The lib is:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-actions
- https://github.com/davestewart/axios-actions

In my application I'm doing the following, but getting no completion:

```
import { Api } from 'axios-actions'
class TestApi extends Api {
    ...
}

const api = new TestApi()
api. // no completion here
```

What do I need to do to make IDEs "see" the methods that are on the base class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the answer here:

- https://medium.com/cameron-nokes/the-30-second-guide-to-publishing-a-typescript-package-to-npm-89d93ff7bccd

You have to:

1. add "declaration": true to your tsconfig.json
2. add "types": "index.d.ts" (or main.d.js) to your package.json

Then publish :)